# C# Error is inconsistent accessibilty: parameter type IPersonRepository is less accessible than method 'PersonController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I implemented the interface below in DictionarypersonRepository. But errors are of inconsistent accessibility in the controller
After ReConstructing the Project the PersonController constructor is shown as inaccessible.

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Person> Get();
    bool TryGet(int id, out Person person);
    Person add(Person person);
}


public class DictionaryPersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    int nextId = 0;
    Dictionary<int, Person> persons = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        return persons.Values.OrderBy(person => person.ID);
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryGet(int id, out Person person)
    {
        return persons.TryGetValue(id, out person);
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Person add(Person person)
    {
        person.ID = nextId++;
        persons[person.ID] = person; 
        return person;
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have made everything public. But still not able to catch the problem of inaccessibility.

This is person class.

```
 public class Person
{

    public Person() { }

    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

The PersonController is having that inaccessiblity error. Any workaround here.
The person controller is below:

```
  public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    IPersonRepository repository;

    public PersonController(IPersonRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    #region GET
    public IQueryable<Person> GetPerson()
    {
        return repository.Get().AsQueryable();
    }

    public Person GetPerson (int id)
    {
        Person person;
        if(!repository.TryGet(id, out person)){
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return person;
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely *certain* that's the only `Person` class? (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to rename `add` to `Add`. Follow .NET naming conventions. I'd rename `Get` to `List` or `GetAll`, too - currently `TryGet` and `Get` don't have the expected relationship.)

Comment: Additionally, you claim that the problems are in the controller - but the error message you're quoting suggests it's in `DictionaryPersonRepository`. Which is it?

Comment: Code as posted works great. I can't reproduce. I guess you have another person class which isn't public.

Comment: @JonSkeet The error points to the methods in DictionaryPersonRepository.

Which I'm trying to call through controller

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't have any other Person Class.

If it's working great i think I should recontruct whole project

Comment: If the errors aren't in the controller, I suggest you edit the question to remove the part that says they *are* in the controller. But yes, it's hard to see what's wrong here.

Comment: please share your project layout if these classes are in different projects.

Comment: @DanielA.White No. They are in same Project.